# I cannot create a project because of Django installation on Windows

Tags: python, django

Please help me find the cause of this problem with my Django installation on Windows.

```
C:\Djangoprojects>django-admin.py startproject mydjangoblog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 4, in <module>
  import pkg_resources
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 3007, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 728, in require
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 626, in resolve
  pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: django==1.5.1
```

I just installed Django 1.5.1 and I remember I had the 1.4.3 before removing it. When I try to create a project, the above error is shown.

After a few adjustments - which included adding the whole directory of Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin to the path variable, this is the error I now get when I try to create a project:

```
C:\Djangoprojects>django-admin.py startproject djangoblog
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
   from django.core import management
 ImportError: No module named django.core
```

The question am now asking myself is this: Where should I put the django folder? In its own place or within python27?

I can import Django through the Python Interactive shell without a problem.
I have also added django-admin.py to the system path variable just in case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: reinstall `django` and that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able to fix this problem. Here is what I did after spending some time on Stackoverflow:

- Leave everything the way it was installed by easy_install when I installed it.
- Make sure that there is one django installation.
- Make sure the `django-admin.py` is inside Python27\Scripts
- To create a django project do: on the command line:
- `python C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject demosite` instead of just: `django-admin.py startproject demosite`.
- The easiest way to make creating projects easier, you can create a **batch** file called `startproject.bat` and save it inside `Python27\Scripts\` folder. Inside that file, add the following: `python C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject %1`
- Now, on your command line,you will be able to simply say : `startproject.bat demosite`

This worked out for me at last and I am happy to say this problem has been solved! I hope this was helpful to others as well.

I want to thank everyone who took their time to answer this question. I could have voted up your answer but I don't have enough points, but until then, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way is to [install pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows), the python package manager on Windows and install Django using pip. Pip will handle the environment variables and paths for you.

```
pip install django --upgrade
```

Comment: I used easy_install to install Django 1.5.1. I had the previous version when I installed the newer one. Should I move the django itself to a different location? and if so, where? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can easily uninstall django by just deleting the folder `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django`

#### new installation

- download django https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.5.1/tarball/
- unzip `Django-1.5.1.tar.gz`
- open terminal(start->run->cmd)
- cd Django-1.5.1
- python setup.py install

that is it.

now try `django-admin.py startproject mydjangoblog`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) to maintain a clean python environment.

1. install virtualenv, and add it to your env-path
2. run cmd `mkvirtualenv django` to create the env for your django project
3. run `pip.exe install` to install needed libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Above issue take place due multiple Django package installed on system. To overcome issue just remove all django package and reinstall latest django package on pc.

## on linux

- $ sudo pip uninstall Django == version
- $ sudo pip install Django